# Trying to download specific type of file from S3 using Boto3 - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download only the most recent .csv files from my S3 bucket and am running into an error that says `"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object."`

I currently have working code that identifies the last modified S3 objects, sorts these objects, and puts them into a list named `latest_files`.

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('chansbucket')

get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj.last_modified.strftime('%s'))

unsorted = []

# filters through the bucket and appends objects to the unsorted list
for file in my_bucket.objects.filter():
    unsorted.append(file)

# sorts last five files in unsorted by last modified time   
    latest_files = [obj.key for obj in sorted(unsorted, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0:5]
```

Now I want to loop through `latest_files` and download only those that end with .csv.

```
for file in latest_files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        s3_resource.meta.client.download_file(my_bucket, file, '/Users/mikechan/projects/TT_product_analyses/raw_csv_files/' + file)
```

Here's where I get the error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Here's the traceback:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-ca90c5ad9c53> in <module>()
      1 for file in latest_files:
      2     if file.endswith('.csv'):
----> 3         s3_resource.meta.client.download_file(my_bucket, str(file), '/Users/mikechan/projects/TT_product_analyses/raw_csv_files/' + str(file))
      4 
      5 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py in download_file(self, Bucket, Key, Filename, ExtraArgs, Callback, Config)
    170         return transfer.download_file(
    171             bucket=Bucket, key=Key, filename=Filename,
--> 172             extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
    173 
    174 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py in download_file(self, bucket, key, filename, extra_args, callback)
    305             bucket, key, filename, extra_args, subscribers)
    306         try:
--> 307             future.result()
    308         # This is for backwards compatibility where when retries are
    309         # exceeded we need to throw the same error from boto3 instead of

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py in result(self)
     71             # however if a KeyboardInterrupt is raised we want want to exit
     72             # out of this and propogate the exception.
---> 73             return self._coordinator.result()
     74         except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
     75             self.cancel()

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py in result(self)
    231         # final result.
    232         if self._exception:
--> 233             raise self._exception
    234         return self._result
    235 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py in _main(self, transfer_future, **kwargs)
    253             # Call the submit method to start submitting tasks to execute the
    254             # transfer.
--> 255             self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
    256         except BaseException as e:
    257             # If there was an exception raised during the submission of task

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py in _submit(self, client, config, osutil, request_executor, io_executor, transfer_future, bandwidth_limiter)
    351                 Bucket=transfer_future.meta.call_args.bucket,
    352                 Key=transfer_future.meta.call_args.key,
--> 353                 **transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
    354             )
    355             transfer_future.meta.provide_transfer_size(

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    318                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    319             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 320             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    321 
    322         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    594         }
    595         request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
--> 596             api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
    597 
    598         service_id = self._service_model.service_id.hyphenize()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _convert_to_request_dict(self, api_params, operation_model, context)
    628                                  context=None):
    629         api_params = self._emit_api_params(
--> 630             api_params, operation_model, context)
    631         request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
    632             api_params, operation_model)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _emit_api_params(self, api_params, operation_model, context)
    658                 service_id=service_id,
    659                 operation_name=operation_name),
--> 660             params=api_params, model=operation_model, context=context)
    661         return api_params
    662 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py in emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    354     def emit(self, event_name, **kwargs):
    355         aliased_event_name = self._alias_event_name(event_name)
--> 356         return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
    357 
    358     def emit_until_response(self, event_name, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py in emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    226                  handlers.
    227         """
--> 228         return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
    229 
    230     def emit_until_response(self, event_name, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py in _emit(self, event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response)
    209         for handler in handlers_to_call:
    210             logger.debug('Event %s: calling handler %s', event_name, handler)
--> 211             response = handler(**kwargs)
    212             responses.append((handler, response))
    213             if stop_on_response and response is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py in validate_bucket_name(params, **kwargs)
    216         return
    217     bucket = params['Bucket']
--> 218     if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
    219         error_msg = (
    220             'Invalid bucket name "%s": Bucket name must match '

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Can you help? I feel like it's something pretty simple, but I'm a total noob and have been pounding my head to my desk forever on this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this line:

```
s3_resource.meta.client.download_file(my_bucket, file, '/Users/mikechan/projects/TT_product_analyses/raw_csv_files/' + file)
```

is that

```
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('chansbucket')
```

is returning a Bucket object while `download_file()` just wants a bucket name as a string, such as:

```
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Also, I think that the `latest_files =...` line should *not* be indented.